# Summing the values of an array to a specific value

Tags: c#

I have an array of integers and I want to determine the values for the array integers such that the sum of the fewest values = some specified number.

```
E.g. int[] array = {1, 2, 4, 8};
specified number = 11;
```

Clearly the values are 1, 2 and 8 (1+2+8=11), but how do I code it in C#?

Comment: Are the values power of 2 ? Or it is just a coincidence.

Comment: Usually you do using a recursive method.  there are thousands of examples on the web.

Comment: I personally have several questions here: Is the array of integers always sorted? Are all integers in the array distinct? What do you mean under "fewest values" probably the least amount of numbers that combine make the target number i.e. if the array is [1,2, 8, 9] the result should be 2+9 = 11 and NOT 1+2+8 = 11?

Comment: @AntonKovachev yes the array is always sorted. By fewest values I mean exactly what you said.

Answer (score 0):

A recursion solution -

Go over all numbers from biggest (last position) to smallest (position 0). (Assuming the array is sorted as you wrote although it doesn't really matter.)

In each iteration, check option A with the number in current position against option B without it, and take the one with less items.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 4, 8 };
    int specifiedNumber = 11;

    int[] result = FindFewestValues(ref array, array.Length - 1, 0, specifiedNumber);
    if (result == null)
        Console.WriteLine("No result");
    else
    {
        foreach (int x in result)
            Console.Write(x + ", ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

static int[] FindFewestValues(ref int[] array, int pos, int tmpSum, int requiredSum)
{
    int currentSum = tmpSum + array[pos];

    if (currentSum == requiredSum)
        return new int[] { array[pos] };

    if (pos == 0)   // Reached last element
        return null;

    if (currentSum > requiredSum)   // Too big, move to next smaller number
        return FindFewestValues(ref array, pos - 1, tmpSum, requiredSum);

    // Use current pos:
    int[] optionA = FindFewestValues(ref array, pos - 1, currentSum, requiredSum);
    // Don't use current pos:
    int[] optionB = FindFewestValues(ref array, pos - 1, tmpSum, requiredSum);

    if (optionA == null)
    {
        return optionB;
    }
    else
    {
        optionA = optionA.Append(array[pos]).ToArray();
        if (optionB == null)
            return optionA;

        if (optionA.Length < optionB.Length)
            return optionA;
        else
            return optionB;
    }
}
```